# Issue with Adding reference Webservice WSDL to VS2010

Tags: webservices, wsdl, wsdl2apex, apex-webservice

I have generated a WSDL for an Apex webservice i have created and trying to call it from a webpage in VS2010.  After adding this as reference i am getting the following error

Error   1   Unable to import binding 'getLeadInfoBinding' from namespace 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/getLeadInfo'.    App_WebReferences/WebReference/

The following is the WSDL i am trying to add
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ju6ZFh_3TSaDZzQVNsa2lOV1E/view?usp=sharing

Please help!

Comment: This tool https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/ thinks the WSDL is OK. Perhaps you should post the question on a VisualStudio forum.

Comment: Are you adding a service reference or a web reference?

Comment: Daniel.... i am doing Add Service Reference -> Advanced -> Add Web Reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** There is now a known issue for this that you can track ["Generate WSDL" generates a WSDL that does not contain the definition of the compound types address and location if API version is 30.0 or above](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XKUAA2)

---

I tried adding it myself as a web reference. This is the message I got:

> Custom tool error: Unable to import WebService/Schema.
>    Unable to import binding 'getLeadInfoBinding' from namespace 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/getLeadInfo'.
>   Unable to import operation 'getLeadAddressByEmail'.
>   **The datatype 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/getLeadInfo:address' is missing.**

Note that the last part here is important. It is telling you that there is no element named address defined in the tns namespace. The `tns` namespace is set to "http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/getLeadInfo".

You will need to add a complex type for address.

```
<!-- Compound datatype: Address -->
<xsd:complexType name="address">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="tns:location">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"  nillable="true" />
        <xsd:element name="country" type="xsd:string"  nillable="true" />
        <xsd:element name="countryCode" type="xsd:string"  nillable="true" />
        <xsd:element name="postalCode" type="xsd:string"  nillable="true" />
        <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string"  nillable="true" />
        <xsd:element name="stateCode" type="xsd:string"  nillable="true" />
        <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"  nillable="true" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<!-- Compound datatype: Location -->
<xsd:complexType name="location">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="latitude" type="xsd:double"  nillable="true" />
    <xsd:element name="longitude" type="xsd:double"  nillable="true" />
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

What release is the Org that you generated the Org on? It seems like a bug that they didn't include the required complex types for address and location.

I've raised this on the developer forum to see if will get picked up as a bug. [Salesforce generated WSDL for Apex webservice missing address complex type](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000ApVpIAK)

Comment: Daniel... thank you very much that fixed the issue. Unfortunately the complete error i am getting if what i have posted was not getting the datatype missing error. I have generated the file in Salesforce test environment Discover Summer 14 environment